# Partial class in F#

Tags: c#, f#

I would like to use [MemoryPack](https://github.com/Cysharp/MemoryPack) in my F# application. Problem is that the class [needs to be declared partial](https://github.com/Cysharp/MemoryPack#quick-start), which F# doesn't support.

Does someone know if there a way to do it in F#?

Comment: That looks like a source generator (which is a newer-ish) C# feature. From the looks of it F# does not have support for source generators (yet - not sure if it's planned either). https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/864

Comment: I've been using FsPickler for many years. It is very fast and supports F# types. Also, you don't have to register types or use attributes or anything like that.

Comment: If you had planned to use it with AlterNats, or maybe MessagePipe, from Cysharp, I can probably help you register FsPickler as the serializer for these. I've done that for AlterNats for my own use.

Comment: FYI, the way C# source generators work is to take the class you flagged (with the [MemoryPackable] attribute) and generate some predefined code at compile time and attach it to your class. You could create a C# project, reference that source generator, attach it to a class, and then view the generated attached source. Then convert that to F# as an inheritable class or something.

Comment: I have tried MessagePack, which doesn't use generators and works, however MemoryPack should be faster which is not bad

Comment: @BentTranberg I tried FsPickler but MessagePack is faster (at least twice in deserialization) and uses half space on disk. I would expect MemoryPack to be even faster, but It is not usable in pure F#, so I will probably stick with MessagePack

Comment: Ok. As for disk space, you might compress, but that too takes time of course. As for the use case, FsPickler is usually good for communication, and not so good for long time persistence.

Comment: Ooops! I called it MessagePack above, but the name is MemoryPack. But I just discovered the same author created MessagePack earlier. There's probably the reason I got the name wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In F#, partial classes are not directly supported like in C#. However, F# allows you to define type extensions for existing classes and modules, which can essentially achieve similar functionality. Instead of using the partial keyword to split the definition of a class into multiple files, you can define a type extension in a separate file and use it to add additional functionality to the original class. For example, suppose you have a C# class Person defined in a file Person.cs
The PersonExtensions module defines a member FullName for the Person class that returns the full name of the person by concatenating the first and last names. Note that the with keyword is used to define a new member for the existing class or module. You can then use the PersonExtensions module in your F# code to add functionality to the Person class defined in C#.

Comment: Looking for a pure F# solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).